# How to convert PDF to HTML on android?

Tags: android, html, pdf, mupdf

I'm trying to display PDF documents in an android aplication. I'm using MuPDF library to decode them as Bitmap, so that they could be displayed in Custom ImageView.

It's working but very memory consuming on some devices, and it's also more challenging to handle zoom. I want to change my approach by converting the PDF to HTML and display it into WebView.

Do you know the best ways/libs to perform this (the MuPDF built-in function systematically renders a blank html file with nothing into the body tag) ?

Comment: were you able to do it? What did you do?